# Is there a way to list all Django registered URL namespaces?

Tags: django

I'm getting an `%s is not a registered namespace` error in Django 1.11. Is there a way to list what all the registered namespaces are?

Comment: Why do you need to list all the url namespaces? It is very inefficient? The registered namespaces are specific to a URL configuration.

Comment: This is mostly for debugging purposes. I'd like to see what changes I make would add which namespaces to this "registered list of namespaces".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do the same what `reverse` actually does: look them up in the `namespace_dict`:

```
from django import urls

url_resolver = urls.get_resolver(urls.get_urlconf())
url_resolver.namespace_dict.keys()
```